Question about failure in Kafka Stream where repartition topic is not consumed and lag continues to accumulate
There is a problem in the Kafka repartition topic where lag continues to increase and is not automatically resolved.
Looking at the log, rebalancing occurred at a certain time, so thread number 19 ↔︎ partition number 6 was mapped.
Afterwards, rebalancing occurred again and it was found that thread number 10 was mapped to partition number 6.
However, after checking the consumer group information with Kafka CLI, we found that the most recent mapping, thread 10, and partition 6 were not mapped, but rather the previous rebalancing, thread 19, and partition 6. .
Note: strimzi version = 0.20.1, kafka version = 2.6.0 schema registry version = 6.1.0
To solve this, I often manually restarted statefulset.
